# Solving $\cos^2{\theta}-\sin{\theta} = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone please help me solve this?

> $$\cos^{2}{\theta}-\sin{\theta} = 1, \quad\theta\in[0^{\circ}, 360^{\circ}]$$

Comment: What have you done so far? We're more than willing to help get you through what has you stumped, but we like to see some work of your own.

Comment: Hint: $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$.

Comment: Is that $360^\circ$ or $360$ radians?

Comment: It is 360 degree AJ Stas

Comment: Also I am working on paper and I am not sure how to post math related questions with all the signs; eg theta

Comment: @barryedx : Click the 'edit'  button in any post to find out how to do the Latex. For theta, use \theta surrounded by dollar signs ( and you know it is _always_ about dollars ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cos^{2}(\theta) - \sin(\theta) = \cos^{2}(\theta) + \sin^{2}(\theta)$, (using Pythagorean Identity)

$\sin^{2}(\theta) + \sin(\theta) = 0$,

let $x = \sin(\theta)$

$x^{2}+ x = 0$

$x=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1^{2}- 4(1)(0)}}{2}$, (Quadratic Formula)

$x = 0$, $x = -1$

substitute $\sin(\theta)$ back in and solve

$0 = \sin(\theta) \Rightarrow \theta = 0^{\circ},180^{\circ},360^{\circ}$

$-1 = \sin(\theta) \Rightarrow \theta = -270^{\circ}$

$\theta = \{0^{\circ},180^{\circ},270^{\circ},360^{\circ}\}$.

Comment: You really don't need the quadratic formula to solve the equation $x^2 + x = 0$.

Comment: @anomaly I am glad Tim used it, because it's more general. OP may not have been aware (as OP couldn't solve this alone)

Comment: Come on! If someone doesn't recognize that the roots of $x^2+x=0$ are 0 and -1 becsuse $x^2+x = x(x+1)$, then, in my opinion, their understanding is weak. This was a blind application of the quadratic formula where it was absolutely not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Notice, we have

$$\cos^2\theta-\sin\theta=1$$
$$1-\sin^2\theta-\sin\theta=1$$
$$-\sin^2\theta-\sin\theta=0$$
$$\sin^2\theta+\sin\theta=0$$
$$\sin\theta(\sin\theta+1)=0$$ $$\sin\theta=0\iff \theta=n(180^\circ)$$
Where, $n$ is any integer.

But for the given interval $[0^\circ, 360^\circ]$, substituting $n=0, 1, 2$, we get

$$ \theta=0^\circ, 180^\circ, 360^\circ$$
Now, $$\sin\theta+1=0$$
$$\sin\theta=-1\iff \theta=2n(180^\circ)-90^\circ$$
But for given interval $[0^\circ, 360^\circ]$, substituting $n=1$ we get

$$\theta= 270^\circ$$
Hence, we have $$\color{red}{\theta}=\left\{\color{blue}{0^\circ, 180^\circ, 270^\circ, 360^\circ} \right\}$$

Comment: Please explain how the negative sign turn to positive in step no. 3, thanks

Comment: OK. Kindly notice, $$1-\sin^2\theta-\sin\theta=1\iff -\sin^2\theta-\sin\theta=0$$ multiply both the sides by $-1$, you will get positive sign on RHS as follows $$-1(-\sin^2\theta-\sin\theta)=0\iff \sin^2\theta+\sin\theta=0$$